# Ubuntu 16.04 wont boot after changing xorg.conf files

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, xorg

I have made a file in `xorg.conf.d` folder to persist some mouse settings, and now when I start ubuntu it stops on black screen with some text displayed.

This started when I added this one `.conf` file, so I guess deleting that file would solve the problem, bot I don't know how to access it from windows7 (dual boot)

**EDIT:**

My `.conf` file looked like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchIsPointer "yes"
# set the following to 1 1 0 respectively to disable acceleration.
    Option "AccelerationNumerator" 1"
    Option "AccelerationDenominator" "0"
    Option "AccelerationThreshold" "4"
EndSection
```

I guess I should have changed the `Identifier` before rebooting PC.

System freezes at this point:

[image]

Comment: What does the text say?

Comment: @StephenBoston well, before it was something else, but now i got command line asking me to login, and after that i got terminal-like environment. I guess it is because I tried to launch ubuntu in recovery mode in the meantime. Should I try to remove the .conf file from recovery mode? This is the file that made a problem, i managed to find it somehow from windows, but can't delete it: http://textuploader.com/dgyrv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to delete Ubuntu files from within Windows. The old trusted program for doing that, [Ext2Fs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/ext2.html), has bricked many Linux partitions recently.

Boot into grub and selected **Advanced Options**. Then select the recovery option for the most recent kernel. Login to the console and then use:

```
$ locate xorg.conf.d
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-trackpoint.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.d.5.gz
```

Find the file in question on the list and use `rm -f /path/filename` to remove it. Then type `reboot`.